# Can I use my 4+4 CPU connector to power my graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Parts:

-MSI GeForce GTX 1070 GAMING X 8G

-Corsair CS450M

My graphics cards needs an extra 6 pin power connector. Can I use the 6 pin CPU connector?

Comment: What motherboard do you have? By looking at your PSU and the cables it came with, you should have an extra cable that can be used for your GPU. You should also note that the card you got has recommends having a 500W PSU. Just keep that in mind in case some things start to act funky like random crashes, random shut offs, etc.

Comment: @DrZoo Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z170-HD3P
My complete build draws around 217 watts. Shouldn't 450w be enough?
Also, the 550w psu from corair has the exact same connectors

Comment: "Can I use the 6 pin CPU connector?" - No; You cannot.  **You need to use a PCI-Express power cable.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your power supply doesn't have the extra GPU plug because it wasn't designed to power a card like that. At max load a stock-clock 1070 will consume over 160 watts, meaning you've got 300 left for the rest of your machine - this is almost certainly not enough at all for a gaming machine (I am assuming you are gaming because you have a 1070).

If you've got a processor in the similar performance range as your GPU, I recommend upgrading to a power supply of 650W or higher. This goes above the 500W recommended for the 1070 to specifically allow for future expansion and overclocking/etc overhead.

For the record, spending a few extra bucks for a name-brand PSU with 80+ ratings is 100% worth the money. If there is one component in your machine that all others rely on, it is the power supply. It is also the only component in the machine capable of frying every single thing plugged into it.